# Получить младшие 8 бит и старшие 24 бита

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

есть в бд число (например 335609856 или 67176448), насколько понимаю эти числа хранятся там в 10-тичной системе, нужно на с++ получить младшие 8 бит и старшие 24 бита этого числа
Верно ли я понимаю, что нужно

```
int n = 335609856;
int low = n & 0xff;
```

Чтобы получить младшие 8 бит числа?

По поводу старших 24 бит, вообще мыслей нет

Comment: А при чём тут БД?

Comment: Это значение хранится там с типом integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Десятичная система в ПО используется, обычно, только для человекочитаемого отображения, компьютерное железо работает с двоичным представлением.

Для получения младших восьми бит Вы верно написали:

```
int low = n & 0xff;
```

Для получения старших двадцати четырёх бит:

```
int high = (n & 0xffffff00U) >> 8;
```

То есть выделяем маской 24 старших бита и сдвигаем их на 8 позиций вправо.

### UPD

Хотя в данном случае (как отметил Harry) маска не нужна, можно обойтись просто сдвигом

```
int high = n >> 8;
```

А маску использовать только чтобы отсечь распространение знакового разряда вправо при сдвиге.

```
int high = (n >>8) & 0x80FFFFFFU;
```

С другой стороны, подобные операции со знаковыми целыми лучше вообще не делать.

Comment: Нюанса со сдвигом отрицательных чисел тут нет? [For negative a, the value of a >> b is implementation-defined (in most implementations, this performs arithmetic right shift, so that the result remains negative).](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

Comment: А зачем маска для 24 бит? И еще — если это `int`, а не `unsigned int`, вот тогда она нужна. Но — **после** сдвига, чтоб отсечь распространение знакового бита вправо... Но опять же, насколько я помню, такие вещи со знаковыми значениями — UB.

Comment: @MBo На сколько помню, есть... Только не помню, какой. Не доводилось работать по маскам со знаковыми числами, всегда использовал беззнаковые.

Comment: @Harry В принципе, маска здесь совершенно не нужна, Вы правы. Я ее оставил с  единственной целью: показать ТС, как она выглядит, на случай, если понадобится выделить старшие биты без сдвига

Comment: @Harry Если `mask` неотрицательная, то выражение `mask & val` также является неотрицательным. Поэтому имеет смысл применить маску до сдвига — так можно избежать проблем со сдвигом отрицательных целых. До C++20 сдвиг отрицательного вправо не UB, а implementation-defined behavior (что всё равно плохо, т.к., например, генерация исключения является допустимым поведением). С C++20 поведение определено (знаковый разряд распространяется при сдвиге), поэтому можно сразу сдвигать, но к результату сдвига всё равно нужна маска, чтобы обнулить распространившийся знаковый бит.

Comment: Даже если сразу сдвигать неотрицательное, то к результату всё равно не помешает применить маску, т.к. `int` может быть более чем 32-битный.

Comment: Значение `0x80000000` не представимо 32-битным типом `int` (а `0x80FFFFFF` и подавно не представимо), следовательно при отрицательном `n` значение `(n >>8) & 0x80FFFFFF` также не представимо типом `int`. Преобразование непредставимого целого в знаковый целочисленный тип `int high = (n >>8) & 0x80FFFFFF;` однозначно определено только с C++20, в более ранних стандартах результат implementation-defined (стандарт C, например считает, что «raising a signal»  — адекватная реакция на такое преобразование).

Comment: @wololo знаковым не представимо. Беззнаковым - вполне. Так что добавил уточняющий суффикс

Comment: В реализациях с 32-битным типом `int` литерал `0x80FFFFFF` имеет тип `unsigned int`. Поэтому добавление суффикса ничего не меняет. При отрицательном `n` результат выражения `(n >>8) & 0x80FFFFFF` больше чем `INT_MAX`. Результат преобразования такого большого целого в тип `int` (здесь: `int high = ...`)  до C++20 является  implementation-defined. [Тест](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7c07e2fc4501972).